# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::appends() error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Error:

**Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::appends() (View: /var/www/resources/views/schools.blade.php)**

Code in blade:

```php
@if(!isset($_REQUEST['fees'])) {{
     $result->appends([
     'centers_of_excellence' => request('centers_of_excellence'),
     'FeesRange' => request('FeesRange'),
     'rankingsortby' => request('rankingsortby'),
     'sortby' => request('sortby'),
     'location' => request('location'),
     'searchItem' => request('searchItem'),
     'searchLocation' => request('searchLocation'),
     'criteria' => request('criteria'),
     'search' => request('search')
     ])->links()
     }}
 @endif
```

in the controller file:

```php
public function paginate($items, $perPage = 15, $page = null, $options = [])
{
   $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
   $items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items);
   return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, [
     'path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()]);
}
```

Not really sure what happened.  It was working few weeks ago.  I tested it again just now and I get an error.

The loop that contains the $result variable:

```php
 @foreach($result as $sch)              
                    <div class="school-wrapper-content col-md-12">                  
                        <div class="school-left col-md-4">                      
                            <div class="school-name">                           
                                <div class="school-icon">                               
                                    <img src="{{asset('images/'.$sch->logo)}}">                         
                                </div>                          
                                <div class="school-title">                              
                                    <a href="{{$sch->url}}">{{strtoupper($sch->name)}}</a>
                                    <br>                                
                                    <span>{{$sch->location}}</span>                         
                                </div>                          
                                <div class="school-image">                              
                                    <img src="{{asset('images/'.$sch->thumbnail)}}">                        
                                </div><br>
                                <div class="school-listing-action"> 
                                <a href="{{$sch->url}}">View Profile</a>                                     
                                </div>                      
                            </div>                  
                        </div>                  
                        <div class="school-right col-md-8">                                             
                            <strong>Board Exam Ranking (Metro Manila):</strong> @if($sch->ranking_metro_manila)
                            {{$sch->ranking_metro_manila}}
                            @else
                            <span>N/A</span>
                            @endif
                            <strong>Board Exam Ranking (Overall):</strong> @if($sch->ranking_philippines)
                            {{$sch->ranking_philippines}}
                            @else
                            <span>N/A</span>
                            @endif              
                            <p>{{ str_limit($sch->describtion, 300) }};
                            </p>                        
                            <div class="score-card">
                                <div class="score-div">                             
                                    <i class="fa fa-star-o" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="">
                                    </i> <span class="score" style="font-size: 1em;"><strong>Term Structure:</strong><span style="color:orange;"> @if($sch->term_structure)
                                        {{$sch->term_structure}} </span>
                                        @else
                                        <span>N/A</span>
                                        @endif</span>                          
                                </div> 
                                <div class="score-div">                             
                                    <i class="fa fa-star-o" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="">
                                    </i> <span class="score" style="font-size: 1em;"><strong>School Starts:</strong><span style="color:orange;"> @if($sch->school_year)
                                        {{$sch->school_year}} </span>
                                        @else
                                        <span>N/A</span>
                                        @endif</span>                          
                                </div>                              
                                <div class="score-div">                             
                                    <i class="fa fa-money" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title=""></i><span class="score" style="font-size: 1em;"><strong> Fees:</strong> <span style="color:orange;"> PHP {{$sch->fees}}</span></span> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="score-div">                             
                                    <i class="fa fa-star-o" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title=""></i> <span class="score" style="font-size: 1em;"><strong>Entrance Exam:</strong> <span style="color:orange;"> @if($sch->entrance_exam)
                                        {{$sch->entrance_exam}} </span>
                                        @else
                                        <span>N/A</span>
                                        @endif</span>                           
                                </div><br><br>
                                <strong>Other Information</strong> <br><br>
                                <div class="score-div">                             
                                    <i class="fa fa-star-o" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title=""></i> <span class="score"><strong>Type:</strong> @if($sch->type)
                                        {{$sch->type}}
                                        @else
                                        <span>N/A</span>
                                        @endif</span>                          
                                </div>                                                  
                                <div class="score-div">                             
                                    <i class="fa fa-star-o" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="">
                                    </i> <span class="score"><strong>Religious Affiliation:</strong> @if($sch->religious_affiliation)
                                        {{$sch->religious_affiliation}}
                                        @else
                                        <span>N/A</span>
                                        @endif</span>                           
                                </div>      
                            </div>                  
                        </div>              
                    </div>  
                    @endforeach
```

Comment: Where is `$result` coming from?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir what do you mean? There is a foreach loop that uses that variable to display search results. `@foreach($result as $sch)`

Comment: How is `$result` defined? What's its content?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir foreach loop code posted above.

Comment: Your code only shows the usage. Where is `$result =`?

Comment: Those are the only places $result is shown.  The page breaks only when I apply a filter to my search results.  when I run a search using the search form, it works fine.

Comment: We can't help you unless you show us the code where `$result` is defined.